# $\Delta\mu = -2$ on Torus $\mathbb T_2\setminus B_r(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Currently, I am reading a paper about Brownian Motion. There is the following statement that I am desperate to understand:

> Let $\mu(y)\equiv\mathbb E_y[\tau_{B_r(x)}]$, [...] then $\Delta\mu=-2$ on $\mathbb T_2\setminus B_r(x).$

Now, I do not have much knowledge about stochastic differential equations thus I basically only came up with this (trivial) thought:

- $\Delta\mu=0$ on $B_r(x)$ since $\mu\equiv 0$ on $B_r(x)$.

I'd be really happy about some advice, even a good book I could read to get familiar with this type of questions. If you need more details about the setup, please let me know!

Comment: Do you know how to do the 1-D version?

Comment: @user10354138 No, sorry, unfortunately not.